# Same column has two different names in two databases

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I am maintaining a code and we have two databases for two currently working applications, with the same code. However, there is this one field that has two different name in these two databases by mistake, and we don't have access to correct the databases now. How can I make my code understand which application is now running and use the correct field in the queries in real time?

**Example:**

```
private integer testField;
```

Query in Database 1:

```
SELECT name, family, test_name from Student;
```

Query in Database 2:

```
SELECT name, family, test from Student;
```

Comment: if you could post a sample query, we might be able to understand. Alias the name of field or change name of field in the script

Comment: Why is it too late to change the database schema?

Comment: @Ven I edited the original question.

Comment: @Kayaman We don't have access to the database anymore.

Comment: Alias `test` as `test_name` in the query

Comment: @Ven What about when the query is being executed in the first environment that uses Database1? Isn't it going to be a problem?

Comment: "it is too late to correct the DB", no. it isn't. it's called "implementing an update"

Comment: A table has _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: You wont change script in first environment anyway

Comment: @Ven But they are using the same code from the same repository.

Comment: You could query the database information schema about which database is being used, then keep that information somewhere and select the column name accordingly. I mean as a really low tech solution.

Comment: Define "view" with normalized column names for each database.

Comment: @Kayaman Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the tag, and the DBMS I am using is oracle.

Comment: Why don't you just fix the name in the database  where it's not correct?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I cannot access the database.

Comment: You said you do not have access to the _correct_ database. I suggested to fix the incorrect database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't have access to neither. I can just edit the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do u have option of changing the query? If yes then try using metadata information of existence of column like :

```
if exists (select 1 from Information_Schema.Columns where Table_Name = '<your table>' and Column = '<the column you want to check for presence>')

 <Your query execution>  

else
<Other query execution>
```

note : An information schema view is one of several methods SQL Server provides for obtaining metadata

Comment: This is a notable solution. I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: Sure ..please update us whether it worked for you or not ?

Answer (score 0):

At the startup of your software you query the database to find out the name of the column, for example with [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) or using the DB specific queries.

Then, assuming you have at least a half decent design instead of SQL peppered everywhere randomly, you modify the queries to use the column name variable. Of course if you have badly designed code (which sounds likely considering the problem in question), this can be hard or impossible to do.

Edit:
You're saying that you "don't have access to the database", but your code at least does. The above could also be used to check for the wrong name in the database, if it exists execute a `ALTER TABLE Student RENAME test TO test_name` statement (example given in Postgres syntax). This assumes that the database user you're connecting as has the permissions to alter the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Do `select * from Student` and from the resulting ResultSet call [getMetaData()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData--) to obtain a [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) instance.

Use [getColumnName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName-int-) to get the table's actual column names.